# Firebase -How to update a RealTimeDatabase Transaction using a Cloud Function

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to update the *views_count* inside my db using Cloud Functions using a transaction.

```
@posts
  @postId_123
     -"url": "https://..."
     -"id": "..."
     -views_count: 17 // increase from 17 to 18
```

I know how to update a Transaction for iOS on the client in Swift but I'm not a native Javascript developer and I'm trying to attempt the same thing using a Cloud Function. I can't find any sample code on updating a Transaction using a Cloud function

client side:

```
lazy var functions = Functions.functions()

func updateViewCount() {

    let data: [String: Any] = ["postId": postId_123, "uid": Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid:]

    functions.httpsCallable("updateViewCount").call(data) { (result, error) in

        if let error = error { return }

        if let result = result {
            print(result)
        }
    }
}

let viewCountObserver = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
func addListenerForViewCount() {

    viewCountObserver.child(postId_123).child("views_count").observe( .value) { (snapshot) in

        let views_count = snapshot.value as? Int ?? 0
        print("the updated views count is: ", views_count)
    }
}
```

Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updateViewCount = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const postId = data.postId;
    const userId = data.uid;
    console.log("postId: " + postId + ", userId: " + userId);

    const postsRef = admin.database().ref('/posts/${postId}/views_count');

    // not sure what to do to update the views_count key using a Transaction from this point on
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ServerValue.Increment` for that:

```
exports.updateViewCount = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const postId = data.postId;
    const userId = data.uid;
    console.log("postId: " + postId + ", userId: " + userId);

    const postsRef = admin.database().ref('posts').child(postId);

    postsRef.child('views_count').set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1))

});
```

You can increment it by any numerical value atomically using that structure. Here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue) for more details.

Comment: thanks, I just found a tweet from Frank Puffen about **ServerValue** https://twitter.com/puf/status/1249700375516643328?lang=en